# How to fix python error (object is not callable)

Tags: python

So I'm just learning Python now, and I wrote this code to practice:

```py
import time
from decimal import Decimal

name = input("\nPlease enter your name: ")

def bmi(weight, height):
    bmi = weight/(height**2)
    if bmi > 29.9:
        report = "obese"
    elif bmi <= 29.9 and bmi > 24.9:
        report = "overweight"
    elif bmi <= 24.9 and bmi > 18.5:
        report = "normal"
    elif bmi <= 18.5:
        report = "underweight"
    else:
        report = "to be lying"
    return (bmi, report)

while True:

    weight = Decimal(input("\nEnter your weight (kg): "))
    if weight == 0:
        print("You can't have a weight of 0. Try again!")
        continue
    if weight < 0:
        print("A negative weight? Really?")
        continue

    height = Decimal(input("Enter your height (cm): "))
    height = height/100

    bmi, report = bmi(weight, height)
    bmi = round(bmi, 1)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n" + name.title() + ", according to your BMI (" + str(bmi) +
        "), you are considered " + report + ".")

    qprompt = input("\nDo you wish to quit? (y/n): ")
    if qprompt == 'y':
        break
    else:
        continue
```

This code seems to return an error after the while loop starts again and I input a weight and height. It works fine the first time, but after I tell it to keep running, and then input the weight and height, it crashes and gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BMI2.py", line 33, in <module>
    bmi, report = bmi(weight, height)
TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not callable
```

I thought I'd ask here for help because I can't figure out the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: The code is using the same name `bmi` for a function and a variable which cause shadowing `function`. Use different names for them.

Comment: To avoid things like that it's advisable to name your functions "properly", meaning: instead of 'bmi' you could call your function 'calculate_bmi' and generally try to start function names with what they do like 'remove_SoapEnv' or 'add_pricingElem'.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the symbol `bmi` in an ambiguous manner.

When you do `bmi, report = bmi(weight, height)`, you essentially override the usage of this symbol as a reference to a function of the same name.

So in the first iteration it references a function, but in the second iteration it references a (non-callable) variable.

Thus, the advantage on a runtime interpreted language is turned against you.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing

```
bmi = round(bmi, 1)
```

which makes `bmi` a number. On the next iteration of your loop, you write

```
bmi, report = bmi(weight, height)
```

using it as a function.

Decide whether `bmi` is the name of your function of your result, and use it consistently